# How to remove horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

When user's device width is more than 480px I'll show him original GIF as a background of my site.

My HTML:

```
<img class="background" src="assets/img/960XAUTO.gif" alt="Pink Smoke Background">
```

My CSS:

```
.background {
    display: block;

    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

When user's device width is less than 480px I increased my GIF's width to 200%, because without increasing the smoke looks very commpessed and skinny:

[image]

So, I do this in my CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-width: $breakpoint) {
    .background {
        position: absolute;
        left: -50%;

        max-width: 200%;
    }
}
```

And here is a problem. As my GIF is increased in 2 times, I get horizontal scrollbar. Just look:

[image]

I really need to increase GIF, so that the smoke looks more widely. How can I remove empty place on the right side, which was created by GIF? Or maybe there is some other way to increase GIF's width? I tried to use `overflow` in the different ways. Also I tried to set `body` width 100% of device screen.

Comment: Why not just use the `background` property instead of an actual image?

Comment: Can you send a url of the image gif or at least the actual dimensions of the gif

Comment: Can you make a fiddle or something please?

Comment: @SzabolcsPáll, there is an actual code with that bug - http://m.gdz4you.com/sandra/index.html

Comment: @Ody, here you can find this site - http://m.gdz4you.com/sandra/index.html

Comment: I changed `position: absolute` to `fixed` in my media rule and it works now for me! Thanks everyone for a help!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS, referring to the element you need (it should be the entire `html` or `body` like in this example, if this is your entire site background, btw):

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `background-attachment:fixed;` in your style

code exact :

```
.background {
      display: block;
      background-attachment:fixed;
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: It didn't help me. But I changed `position: absolute` to `fixed` in my media rule and it works now for me!

Answer (score 0):

You should try using background center with optional scaling percentages.
The full edit is here https://plnkr.co/edit/wZZqiC3awyEzHLPpxYBI

```
.bg{
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: no-repeat center/80% url("http://m.gdz4you.com/sandra/assets/img/960XAUTO.gif");
     background-size: cover; 
}
```

and ofcourse just drop a div

```
<div class="bg"></div>
```